# Redirect to Specific screen from AppDelegate : On tap Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

For **messaging application**.

The structure is

> TabBarController -> NavigationController->View_One -> View_Two.  Whenever user tab on notification, i need to redirect to View_2 from appdelegate.m **[DidReceiveRemoteNotification method]**.

This current code helps me to land on View_One. How can i goto View_Two without affecting NavigationController and Tabbar controller functionality?

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive||application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

    UIStoryboard *mainSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:MAIN_STORYBOARD bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [mainSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TAB_BAR_ID];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: its opens upto your `2` index

Comment: Edited my question, please check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive||application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

    UIStoryboard *mainSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:MAIN_STORYBOARD bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [mainSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TAB_BAR_ID];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    UINavigationController *nav = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    View2 *destViewController = (View2*) [self.nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [nav pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];


}
```

**Choice-2**

I am not sure above method will work, in here we go for some hacky methods , In here as per your code follows we use `NSUSerdefault` concept

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive||application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

    UIStoryboard *mainSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:MAIN_STORYBOARD bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [mainSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TAB_BAR_ID];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"APNS" forKey:@"openVC"]
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

retrieve Like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad // or call in loadView Method 
{
 if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"openVC"]isEqualToString:@"APNS"])
{
 // Navigate to second VC
 }
 }
```

**finally**

on your secondVC

```
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"openVC"];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Tq. Here you didn't mention about RootViewController. Is it Ok?

Comment: @Ramdy - no need, try once , if you are not get the answer we go for some other tricky way.

Comment: in 1st method,     View2 *destViewController = (View2*) [self.nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
     this code returns, View1's reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121071/discussion-between-ramdy-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Ya, i used 2nd choice-2. Works fine.